# Sync all Documents directory into iCloud

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icloud

Is there a way to make my Documents directory synchronized with iCloud?

I have setup all permissions and entitlements, but have no idea what to do next.

Could you please provide a swift code snippet or point into a direction I should look to?

Comment: Are you asking about documents directory on Windows? Mac?

Answer (score 2):

You can use iCloud's CloudKit services for this.

Have a look at the Quick Start Guide for iCloud's Cloudkit [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/AddingAssetsandLocations/AddingAssetsandLocations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH6-SW2).

Comment: Thanks, but I need iCloud.

Comment: If you had read the link I've provided, you would already know that CloudKit is a service that's part of iCloud. CloudKit is one of three app services provided by iCloud. The other iCloud app services—key-value storage and iCloud documents—also appear in the iCloud settings in Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

When I needed to keep NSUserDefaults in sync via iCloud in simple apps, I used: [MKiCloudSync by Mugunth Kumar](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKiCloudSync). While still Objective-C, it's pretty straightforward to use.

If you need iCloud Documents sync, you might check out [iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync](https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync). Of course, this is a bit more work, but still easier than implementing all the methods by yourself.

Have a nice day,

@cdf1982

Answer (score 2):

You can use iCloudDrive of iOS 8 to store documents in iCloud Drive..

Refer below links for iCloud set up for your app.

https://unionassets.com/iosnative/icloud-setup-25

http://www.raywenderlich.com/83116/beginning-cloudkit-tutorial

Refer below for saving document to iCloudDrive.

[Save iOS 8 Documents to iCloud Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051437/save-ios-8-documents-to-icloud-drive)

Refer below to view the documents which you have saved in iCloudDrive

https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync

Hope all the above links are useful to get the task done..!

Answer (score 2):

The following 3 steps should get you going:

Step 1: [Preparing the app to use iCloud Storage](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Preparing_an_iOS_8_App_to_use_iCloud_Storage#Ubiquity_Container_URLs)

Step 2: [Learing to manage your files using the UIDocument Class](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Managing_Files_using_the_iOS_8_UIDocument_Class)

Step 3: [Using iCloud Storage in your app](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_iCloud_Storage_in_an_iOS_8_Application)

Cheers,
Istvan