# iOS ubiquitous file not uploaded to iCloud (simulator)

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-drive

I'm trying to save arbitrary files from my application's sandbox to iCloud Drive, on the iOS 10.3 simulator.

iCloud Drive is enabled and I'm signed in. If I open the iCloud Drive app on the simulator, I see files in there.

*So, in my app*:

I obtain the container with:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil]
```

Which gives me something like this:

`file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F873A728-0314-4666-A137-830FF6280F05/data/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~com~me~iclouduploadtest/`

Then I make my sandboxed file ubiquitous, like this:

```
NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:url destinationURL:ubiquityURL error:&error]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Error occurred: %@", error);
}
```

No error is reported, and if I look on disk I see the file disappear from `url` and appear inside the ubiquity container (the path obtained earlier).

Great! So my file is in iCloud! Or... not.

- File is not visible in icloud.com, nor in iCloud Drive app on the simulator
- NSMetadataQuery run on the simulator does not find the file in iCloud
- Even after using `Trigger iCloud sync` in simulator debug menu
- I try `brctl log --wait --shorten` and trigger the sync again. No errors are reported. Lots of `starting sync down` but nothing about syncing *up*, for any application.

**Why isn't my file being uploaded to iCloud?**

**Am I doing something wrong, or missing a step?**

**Does iCloud Drive upload not work on the 10.3 simulator?**

Comment: Try follow the steps described in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27358392/5031210, it helped me a lot when setting up iCloud Drive the first time. iCloud Drive does work on the simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sigh* I uninstalled the app, disabled and re-enabled iCloud Drive, incremented the version and build numbers, and reinstalled the app. Now it works.

Comment: hey @thenextman, have you found what's the problem? Sometimes my app stops syncing and I have to disable and re-enable iCloud Drive to start working again. Do you know if there is some explanation for this to happen?

Comment: Hi @Tiago Pereira, it sounds like a different problem.

Comment: I think they are quite similar. When I get this problem, the file is not visible in iCloud and I do not receive any information via NSMetadataQuery. And both of our problems are solved using the same approach by disable and re-enable iCloud Drive.

Comment: Hmmm ok... Well I don't know more than what's above. It didn't work; I did the steps in my answer, and it works. Sorry I don't know the reason...