# Ubiquitous Container is not visible on icloud drive

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, ubiquitycontainer

I am developing an iOS app which download the file from local server and after syncs to iCloud. But i am not able to see my application container nor the files on iCloud drive. But i can see them in **settings >> iCloud >> iCloud drive >> storage >>Manage Storage** with my default iOS icon. I have done the things like bumping the bundle version and added the following keys in info.plist.

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
    <dict>
        <key>iCloud.com.abc.MyApp</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
            <string>MyApp</string>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
            <string>Any</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I  have used this code to save on iCloud -

```
document = (MyDocument *)[[UIDocument alloc]initWithFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",filePath]]];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSError *error;
   bool isStored = [fm setUbiquitous:true itemAtURL:[document fileURL] destinationURL:[[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents" isDirectory:true] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[document fileType]] error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error is%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }           
if (isStored) {
                NSLog(@"saved on cloud");
            }
```

Note: My application is not live.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30537829

Comment: @Jitendra Patil  did you got any solution for this ??

Comment: Same problem.  Exact same problem here.  Would be great if someone knew how to debug a product that Apple seems to value but doesn't seem to support.