# How to make app iCloud folder show up on other devices

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-drive

I am trying to add iCloud drive capabilities to my existing iPhone app, basically just to be able to store files in iCloud drive, such that the user has access to them on all his devices.

I have followed the steps to enable iCloud drive capabilities:

- Enable iCloud Documents capability in the "Signing and Capabilities" in XCode for the project target, and the iCloud container
- Added the `NSUbiquitousContainers` key to the `Info.plist`.
- The app ensures the `Documents` folder in the ubiquity container exists
- The app writes a test file into the `Documents` folder at start-up.
- Stepped the build version to a higher number

So far, it is working locally on the iPhone: the app folder is visible in the `Files` app on the same phone, and the test file is visible there as well.

But the app folder is not visible on iCloud.com, and not in Finder on my MacBook. I can see the `Downloads` folder with the same content in iCloud Drive on both platforms, so I am sure that I am logged in with the same AppleID as on the iPhone.

What else do I need to do to make the app folder visible in iCloud? If it is an issue because the app update has not been released yet, how can I test the functionality before releasing it?

---

I have looked at other questions that have encountered the same problems, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385940/why-my-app-is-not-shown-in-icloud-drive-folder) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/43227), but I think I have done all the steps recommended in those answers (the practical ones, requesting a new AppID is obviously not possible for an existing app).

The Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW24) is extremely bloated, so it is hard to distill what the basic steps are that you need to follow.

Info.plist settings (obviously with `MyApp` replaced with my app's name):

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
<dict>
    <key>iCloud.com.MyApp.MyApp</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
        <string>MyApp</string>
        <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
        <string>Any</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be that the answer is: just wait. I did not change anything in the code, and did not even run it again. A day later the files and folders showed up both on icloud.com and on my MacBook.

Strange that it takes so long, though.

Comment: I've worked for about 10 hours now trying to get this to work. I'll see what happens tomorrow. If this is the answer you are the hero of the day.

Comment: well..........?

Comment: I guess he's still waiting!