# Can't see my app inside the iCloud Drive folder

Tags: swift, swiftui, icloud, icloud-drive, icloud-documents

Okay, so I have been searching all over and couldn't find a working solution,
I'm using iCloud Documents to sync between device's app documents and I just can't get the app to appear in the iCloud Drive in files app, I can see all the files between device and download each file, but can't see any of them in the iCloud Drive or see the app's directory but in the local folder "On My iPhone".

I tried increasing the build number, and double checked a couple times my bundle name and iCloud container and ubiquity container:

bundle is dorsahar.appname
and iCloud container is iCloud.dorsahar.appname and ubiquity is the same as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make app iCloud folder show up on other devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68227039/how-to-make-app-icloud-folder-show-up-on-other-devices)

Comment: Appreciated! I actually got it fixed a few hours ago but that was the solution!

Comment: Great I added it as an answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

According to this you need to make a Documents folder in the ubiquity container and the Folder that appears inside iCloud Drive is a symlink to that

[How to make app iCloud folder show up on other devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68227039/how-to-make-app-icloud-folder-show-up-on-other-devices)