# Default ubiquitous container missing from ICloud Drive, Yosemite

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, osx-yosemite, icloud

I am trying to set up an ICloud container to load the documents for my app.
My NsfileManager's UbiquityIdentityToken is always nil. I couldn't even find any folder (container with default app name) in the iCloud drive.

Project Capabilities:
:[image: Project Capabilities]

Entitlements:
[image: Entitlements]

File.Pllist:

[image: File.Pllist]

Project General settings:
 [image: General Settings]

Please let me know if you need any further details. I am using XCode 6.4

I did follow the instructions from [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html) and followed suggestions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203697/exposing-an-apps-ubiquitous-container-to-icloud-drive-in-ios-8)

This is the first time I am working with XCode, what am I missing? There were no build or compile errors.